# How to set up auto-closing curly braces in VS Code for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, curly-braces

I am new in learning C# and wondered if it is possible to set auto closing curly braces for e.g. when using string interpolation for a faster experience in VS Code?

```
int variable;
Console.WriteLine($"Example {variable}");
```

In the example i needed to press ( once the closing brace was automatically put there, but { and } needed to press both in order to complete the code.

I want to langauge-specifically do this.

Comment: I thought it does go out of the box?!? Have you installed the C# Extension from OmniSharp? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp

Comment: Yep, it was my first thing to do. And disabled every other extension that i don't need. (So basically everything except theme, icons and better comments)